# Javascript loop looses context in recursion

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

Here's an example:

```
function try2RecurseIt() {
  var MyArr = [[1,[2,3],4],[5,6],[7,8,[9,0]]];
  letsDance(MyArr);
}

function letsDance(arr) {
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    console.log("arr["+i+"] "+ arr[i]);
    if (arr[i].constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1) { // isArray check
      letsDance(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I expected it would loop through *all* elements, but the result:

```
// arr[0] 1,2,3,4
// arr[0] 1
// arr[1] 2,3
// arr[0] 2
// arr[1] 3
```

Somewhere my `letsDance()` function loses context and I can't figure out where. What am I doing wrong?

Yes, I know about `forEach`, but I'm trying to understand where I'm wrong here. Further I'm going to use this method to parse `htmlElements.children[n]` which are not arrays.

I'm learning JavaScript and need to understand the basics without using any libraries.

Comment: What do you mean "loses context"? Each function has its own execution context, how can that be lost?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is failure to keep variables local:

```
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
```

here, *i* becomes global on the first loop so subsequent loops increment it, use:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Yes, my bad, it works fine after Your correction, thank You!but it is an example, and the my real code still doesn't work correct (no global variables there). I'll prepare another question.  Thank You!

Comment: Finally I found error in my real code. Of course, I forgot to use 'var' (in other place of code, but also influencing on passing values). Thank U!

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your code is that `i` is a global variable. Therefore each call to the function rewrites the same `i` and `i` keeps being reset to 0.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it works fine after Your correction, thank You!but it is an example, and the my real code still doesn't work correct (no global variables there). I'll prepare another question.  Thank You!

Comment: You should also be aware of closures. Google "closure" or search SO for "closure" to understand how functions work in javascript.

Comment: Sure I will. Finally I found error in my real code. Of course, I forgot to use 'var' (in other place of code, but also influencing on passing values). Thank U!